# How to get consumer key and and consumer secret for gmail api?

Tags: api, gmail, google-data-api

I am trying to use Gmail php xoath php samples, however it requires to enter consumer key and consumer secret which I could not find how to obtain in Gmail api documentation. Does any one know how to obtain them or know of any related documentation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `anonymous` / `anonymous` and `HMAC-SHA1` signature for applications that are not registered with Google. For applications registered with Google, you should use the application domain as consumer key and the consumer secret depends on the signing method (your private key for `RSA-SHA1` and the secret generated during the registration for `HMAC-SHA1`). More details at [Signing OAuth requests](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref.html#SigningOAuth).

Note that as far as I know, HMAC-SHA1 for registered applications is supported only for applications installed by the Google Apps admins.

Comment: Thank you heaps. Finally I found the solution.

Comment: What was the solution i have the same problem.. please let me know!

Answer (score 3):

In the google example to access to Gmail using IMAP & OAuth, you can find this code:

```
public static OAuthConsumer getAnonymousConsumer() {
return new OAuthConsumer(null, "anonymous", "anonymous", null);
}
```

Hope this helps